# Not getting the from data from PugJS form in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, forms, express, pug

I am trying to add an authentication form where users enter their credentials and if their credentials are correct, I want to redirect them to a route. So, I have created a middleware [login.js](https://github.com/raghav4/shortlink/blob/master/middleware/login.js), which renders the pug template and post a request on form submission. The post method is working but I am not getting the values of the pug form in `req.body`. What do I do?

Here's the `admingLogin.pug` file

```html
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    meta(charset='UTF-8')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
    meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='ie=edge')
    link(rel='icon', href='../client/assets/favicon/login.ico', type='image/x-icon')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css')
    title Admin
  body
    .ui.middle.aligned.center.aligned.grid
      .column
        form.ui.large.form(action='/auth' method='post')
          .ui.stacked.secondary.segment
            .field
              .ui.left.icon.input
                p Log-in as an admin to create custom links
            .field
              .ui.left.icon.input
                i.user.icon
                input(type='text', name='username', placeholder='Username')
            .field
              .ui.left.icon.input
                i.lock.icon
                input(type='password', name='password', placeholder='Password')
            button(type="submit").ui.fluid.large.teal.submit.button Login
          .ui.error.message
    style.
      body>.grid {
      height: 100% !important;
      }
      .image {
      margin-top: -100px !important;
      }
      .column {
      max-width: 450px !important;
      margin-left: 55px !important;
      margin-right: 55px !important;
      }
      body {
      background: #30E8BF;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #FF8235, #30E8BF);
      background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF8235, #30E8BF);
      }
```

Here's the [link](https://github.com/raghav4/ShortLink) to the complete project and the link to the route is [here](https://github.com/raghav4/ShortLink/blob/410044b4c9367a82d0390422934de1e19400514b/routes/urlShorten.js#L48). The middleware is passed [here](https://github.com/raghav4/ShortLink/blob/410044b4c9367a82d0390422934de1e19400514b/routes/custom.js#L7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POST from your HTML is sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You need to configure `body-parser` to handle such a type.

Currently, based on the code you added, it is only capable of handling `application/json`.

Try adding the following line below `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```